# ReactJS Datepicker multiple dates selection

Tags: reactjs, datepicker

I am making a form in `reactJS` which has a datepicker from https://reactdatepicker.com/ and my question is:

Is there any option to have multiple dates selection in one datepicker ??

According to documentation there isn't or maybe I missed something ?

I would appreciate any help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can try working with highligthedDates. Add and remove date via the onChange event and style the calendar to meet your demand. That should be easier than adding another  datepicker package.

Answer (score 3):

There are many node modules out there, and if you have one that doesn't fit your needs (I also did some looking into your supplied datepicker, and it seems like you're correct that it does not have multiple date selection), you can find others. [This one](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-dates), by airbnb, is a date *range* picker, and [react-multiple-datepicker](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-multiple-datepicker) is one where you can select multiple unrelated dates.

Answer (score 2):

I know it's been a while since this question has been asked but I needed this exact feature, found a simple workaround if it helps:

```
export function DemoDatePicker() {
 // range demo
 const [startDate, setStartDate] = useState(null);
 const [endDate, setEndDate] = useState(null);

 function handleDateChange(date) {
    // initial change: start by setting the startDate
    if (!startDate && !endDate) {
      setStartDate(date);
     // startDate has been set, set the end date
    } else if (startDate && !endDate) {
     setEndDate(date);
    }

    // user is choosing another range => set the start date
    // and set the endDate back to null
    if (startDate && endDate) {
      setStartDate(date);
      setEndDate(null);
    }
 }

  return (
    <div>
      <DatePicker
        onChange={(date) => handleDateChange(date)}
        selectsStart={true}
        selected={startDate}
        startDate={startDate}
        endDate={endDate}
        inline={true}
      />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I recently viewed your question.

you can use `selectsStart` option followed by `startDate={-your start date here-}`, `endDate={-your end date here-}`, and end your selects using Keyword `selectsEnd`. That's all.

```
    <DatePicker
      selectsStart
      startDate={startDate}
      endDate={endDate}
      selectsEnd
      inline
    />
```